# Forcing a valid If/Else Scanner input from Console

Tags: java, string, if-statement

Basically, I want the user to pick either a `Dwarf` or `Human`.
The problem is, if another choice is made, such as `Cyclops` the process ends.

Below is my code.

```
//Race.java
public class Race{
    private String race;
    private int might;
    private int reflex;
    private int durability;
    private int smarts;
    private int bravado;

    public Race(){
    }
    public String getRace(){
        return race;
    }
    public void setRace(String race){
        this.race = race;
    }
    public int getMight(){
        return might;
    }
    public void setMight(int might){
        this.might = might;
    }
    public int getReflex(){
        return reflex;
    }
    public void setReflex(int reflex){
        this.reflex = reflex;
    }
    public int getDurability(){
        return durability;
    }
    public void setDurability(int durability){
        this.durability = durability;
    }
    public int getSmarts(){
        return smarts;
    }
    public void setSmarts(int smarts){
        this.smarts = smarts;
    }
    public int getBravado(){
        return bravado;
    }
    public void setBravado(int bravado){
        this.bravado = bravado;
    }
}
```

```
//RaceCreator.java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class RaceCreator{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Race dwarf = new Race();
        dwarf.setRace("Dwarf");
        dwarf.setMight(4);
        dwarf.setReflex(2);
        dwarf.setDurability(4);
        dwarf.setSmarts(3);
        dwarf.setBravado(2);

        Race human = new Race();
        human.setRace("Human");
        human.setMight(3);
        human.setReflex(3);
        human.setDurability(3);
        human.setSmarts(3);
        human.setBravado(3);

        System.out.println("Are you Human or Dwarf?");
        Scanner scanRace = new Scanner(System.in);
        String inputRace = scanRace.next();
        //System.out.println("Hello down there " + inputRace + "!");
        if (inputRace.equalsIgnoreCase("Dwarf")) {
            System.out.println("Greetings " + dwarf.getRace() + "!");
            System.out.println("Your Might is " + dwarf.getMight() + " ... Impressive!");
            System.out.println("Your Reflex is " + dwarf.getReflex() + " ... Below Average.");
            System.out.println("Your Durability is " + dwarf.getDurability() + " ... Impressive!");
            System.out.println("Your Smarts are " + dwarf.getSmarts() + " ... Average.");
            System.out.println("Your Bravado is " + dwarf.getBravado() + " ... Below Average.");
        } else if (inputRace.equalsIgnoreCase("Human")) {
            System.out.println("Greetings " + human.getRace() + "!");
            System.out.println("Your Might is " + human.getMight() + " ... Average.");
            System.out.println("Your Reflex is " + human.getReflex() + " ... Average.");
            System.out.println("Your Durability is " + human.getDurability() + " ... Average.");
            System.out.println("Your Smarts are " + human.getSmarts() + " ... Average.");
            System.out.println("Your Bravado is " + human.getBravado() + " ... Average.");
        }
    }
}
```

I have looked up numerous tutorials about `while`, `do` and `break` but they are all using integers, or just 1 option, instead of 2 (`Dwarf` or `Human`).

Comment: A while loop with a String is just like an if block with a String. Come on and give it a try, something you should always do before coming here, and I'll bet that you'll be pleasantly surprised at what you can do. Note that I deleted some of the distracting cruft from your question.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that you have no more code after the if-else-if statement, therefore, the main method will return and so the program ends (programs end once the end of the main method is reached).

```
if (inputRace.equalsIgnoreCase("Dwarf")) {
    // ...
} else if (inputRace.equalsIgnoreCase("Human")) {
    // ...
}
// There is no code after this, so the main method will return and the program will end.
```

To have the program continue until the user has chosen a valid choice, use the following code to retrieve input from the user.

```
String inputRace = null;
System.out.print("Please choose either a dwarf or human: ");
while(scanRace.hasNextLine()){
    inputRace = scanRace.nextLine(); // Get the next line of input
    // Exit the loop if the choice is valid
    if(inputRace.equalsIgnoreCase("dwarf") || inputRace.equalsIgnoreCase("human")) break;
    else System.pout.print("Invalid choice, please enter the choice again: ");
}
// "inputRace" now holds the valid choice (either dwarf or human)
// After this should be your current if-else block.
```

instead of

```
String inputRace = scanRace.next();
```

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I didn't say another if-block should be added. The OP asked why the code was finishing, and so I explained why.

Answer (score 0):

This will prompt you till tou wont insert Dwarf or Human

Instead this:

```
System.out.println("Are you Human or Dwarf?");
Scanner scanRace = new Scanner(System.in);
String inputRace = scanRace.next();
```

Use this:

```
Scanner scanRace = new Scanner(System.in);
String inputRace;
while(scanRace.hasNext()){ // or while(true)
    System.out.println("Are you Human or Dwarf?");
    inputRace = scanRace.next();
    if(inputRace.equalsIgnoreCase("Dwarf") || inputRace.equalsIgnoreCase("Human"))
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you created for your program was either A or B with no bounce back if either Dwarf or human was not selected. You could use a **While loop**.

```
// for a single person
String race = racescan.next(); //you create a scanner class and retrieve it
int loopCounter =0;

while(loopCounter < 1)
{
    if (race.equalsIgnoreCase("dwarf") {
        System.out.println("Greetings " + dwarf.getRace() + "!");
        System.out.println("Your Might is " + dwarf.getMight() + " ... Impressive!");
        System.out.println("Your Reflex is " + dwarf.getReflex() + " ... Below Average.");
        System.out.println("Your Durability is " + dwarf.getDurability() + " ... Impressive!");
        System.out.println("Your Smarts are " + dwarf.getSmarts() + " ... Average.");
        System.out.println("Your Bravado is " + dwarf.getBravado() + " ... Below Average.");

        loopCounter++;
     } 
     else if (race.equalsIgnoreCase("Human")) {
        System.out.println("Greetings " + human.getRace() + "!");
        System.out.println("Your Might is " + human.getMight() + " ... Average.");
        System.out.println("Your Reflex is " + human.getReflex() + " ... Average.");
        System.out.println("Your Durability is " + human.getDurability() + " ... Average.");
        System.out.println("Your Smarts are " + human.getSmarts() + " ... Average.");
        System.out.println("Your Bravado is " + human.getBravado() + " ... Average.");

        loopCounter++;
    }
}    // end of while loop
```

If you want to create it for a two person game then you cand just up the loopcount you need to achieve before exiting.

Comment: Putting huge ifs to cycle +1, instead od `loopCounter++;` I would use simple: `break;`

Comment: A flaw with this is that it won't allow the race to be retrieved from outside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Brilliant responses everyone! (Especially **SamTebbs33**) I appreciate all of them so much, thank you!!! Also, if any other beginner Java members on this forum are interested, I will be constantly working on this simple "Choose your own adventure/RPG" style game and if you send me a private message, we can slowly build upon this basic foundation into something more rich & complex over the coming months.

This is now what the code looks like and it is working perfectly!

Race.java

```
public class Race{
    private String race;
    private int might;
    private int reflex;
    private int durability;
    private int smarts;
    private int bravado;
    private int fortune;
    private int sense;

    public Race(){
    }
    public String getRace(){
        return race;
    }
    public void setRace(String race){
        this.race = race;
    }
    public int getMight(){
        return might;
    }
    public void setMight(int might){
        this.might = might;
    }
    public int getReflex(){
        return reflex;
    }
    public void setReflex(int reflex){
        this.reflex = reflex;
    }
    public int getDurability(){
        return durability;
    }
    public void setDurability(int durability){
        this.durability = durability;
    }
    public int getSmarts(){
        return smarts;
    }
    public void setSmarts(int smarts){
        this.smarts = smarts;
    }
    public int getFortune(){
        return fortune;
    }
    public void setFortune(int fortune){
        this.fortune = fortune;
    }
    public int getBravado(){
        return bravado;
    }
    public void setBravado(int bravado){
        this.bravado = bravado;
    }
    public int getSense(){
        return sense;
    }
    public void setSense(int sense){
        this.sense = sense;
    }

}
```

RaceCreator.java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class RaceCreator {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Race dwarf = new Race();
        dwarf.setRace("Dwarf");
        dwarf.setMight(7);
        dwarf.setReflex(5);
        dwarf.setDurability(7);
        dwarf.setSmarts(6);
        dwarf.setBravado(5);
        dwarf.setFortune(7);
        dwarf.setSense(5);

        Race human = new Race();
        human.setRace("Human");
        human.setMight(6);
        human.setReflex(6);
        human.setDurability(6);
        human.setSmarts(6);
        human.setBravado(6);
        human.setFortune(6);
        human.setSense(6);

        Profession gambler = new Profession();
        gambler.setProfession("Gambler");

        Profession bard = new Profession();
        bard.setProfession("Bard");

        Profession gladiator = new Profession();
        gladiator.setProfession("Gladiator");

        Profession pickpocket = new Profession();
        pickpocket.setProfession("Pickpocket");

        Profession wanderer = new Profession();
        wanderer.setProfession("Wanderer");

        Profession scholar = new Profession();
        scholar.setProfession("Scholar");

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Welcome to Choice!");
        System.out.println();

        Scanner scanRace = new Scanner(System.in);
        String inputRace = null;
        System.out.println("Are you Human or Dwarf?");
        while (scanRace.hasNextLine()) {
            inputRace = scanRace.nextLine();
            if (inputRace.equalsIgnoreCase("Dwarf") || inputRace.equalsIgnoreCase("Human"))
                break;
            else System.out.println("Please choose a valid race.");
        }
        System.out.println();
        if (inputRace.equalsIgnoreCase("Dwarf")) {
            System.out.println("Greetings " + dwarf.getRace() + "!");
            System.out.println("Your Might is " + dwarf.getMight() + " ... Impressive!");

            //if(dwarf.getMight() < 6 ){ System.out.println("Average");} else if (dwarf.getMight() > 6 ){ System.out.println("Great!");}

            System.out.println("Your Reflex is " + dwarf.getReflex() + " ... Below Average.");
            System.out.println("Your Durability is " + dwarf.getDurability() + " ... Impressive!");
            System.out.println("Your Smarts are " + dwarf.getSmarts() + " ... Average.");
            System.out.println("Your Bravado is " + dwarf.getBravado() + " ... Below Average.");
            System.out.println("Your Fortune is " + dwarf.getFortune() + " ... Impressive!");
            System.out.println("Your Sense is " + dwarf.getSense() + " ... Below Average.");
        } else if (inputRace.equalsIgnoreCase("Human")) {
            System.out.println("Greetings " + human.getRace() + "!");
            System.out.println("Your Might is " + human.getMight() + " ... Average.");
            System.out.println("Your Reflex is " + human.getReflex() + " ... Average.");
            System.out.println("Your Durability is " + human.getDurability() + " ... Average.");
            System.out.println("Your Smarts are " + human.getSmarts() + " ... Average.");
            System.out.println("Your Bravado is " + human.getBravado() + " ... Average.");
            System.out.println("Your Fortune is " + human.getFortune() + " ... Average.");
            System.out.println("Your Sense is " + human.getSense() + " ... Average.");
        }
        System.out.println();
        Scanner scanProfession = new Scanner(System.in);
        String inputProfession = null;
        System.out.println("What was your previous Profession? Gambler, Bard, Gladiator, Pickpocket, Wanderer or Scholar?");
        while (scanProfession.hasNextLine()) {
            inputProfession = scanProfession.nextLine();
            System.out.println();
            if (inputProfession.equalsIgnoreCase("Gambler") ||
                    inputProfession.equalsIgnoreCase("Bard") ||
                    inputProfession.equalsIgnoreCase("Gladiator") ||
                    inputProfession.equalsIgnoreCase("Pickpocket") ||
                    inputProfession.equalsIgnoreCase("Wanderer") ||
                    inputProfession.equalsIgnoreCase("Scholar"))
                break;
            else System.out.println("Please choose a valid profession.");
        }
        if (inputProfession.equalsIgnoreCase("Gambler")) {
            System.out.println("Luck be with you ... " + gambler.getProfession() + ".");
            System.out.println("     *+1 Bravado, +2 Sense, +3 Fortune*");
            dwarf.setBravado(dwarf.getBravado() + 1);
            human.setBravado(human.getBravado() + 1);
            dwarf.setSense(dwarf.getSense() + 2);
            human.setSense(human.getSense() + 2);
            dwarf.setFortune(dwarf.getFortune() + 3);
            human.setFortune(human.getFortune()+3);
        } else if (inputProfession.equalsIgnoreCase("Bard")) {
            System.out.println("Music to my ears ... " + bard.getProfession() + ".");
            System.out.println("     *+1 Fortune, +2 Smarts, +3 Bravado*");
            dwarf.setFortune(dwarf.getFortune()+1);
            human.setFortune(human.getFortune()+1);
            dwarf.setSmarts(dwarf.getSmarts()+2);
            human.setSmarts(human.getSmarts()+2);
            dwarf.setBravado(dwarf.getBravado()+3);
            human.setBravado(human.getBravado()+3);
        } else if (inputProfession.equalsIgnoreCase("Gladiator")) {
            System.out.println("Freedom from savagery ... " + gladiator.getProfession() + ".");
            System.out.println("     *+1 Reflex, +2 Might, +3 Durability*");
            dwarf.setReflex(dwarf.getReflex()+1);
            human.setReflex(human.getReflex()+1);
            dwarf.setMight(dwarf.getMight()+2);
            human.setMight(human.getMight()+2);
            dwarf.setDurability(dwarf.getDurability()+3);
            human.setDurability(human.getDurability()+3);
        } else if (inputProfession.equalsIgnoreCase("Pickpocket")) {
            System.out.println("A cunning ... " + pickpocket.getProfession() + ".");
            System.out.println("     *+1 Fortune, +2 Sense, +3 Reflex*");
            dwarf.setFortune(dwarf.getFortune() + 1);
            human.setFortune(human.getFortune() + 1);
            dwarf.setSense(dwarf.getSense() + 2);
            human.setSense(human.getSense() + 2);
            dwarf.setReflex(dwarf.getReflex() + 3);
            human.setReflex(human.getReflex() + 3);
        } else if (inputProfession.equalsIgnoreCase("Wanderer")) {
            System.out.println("To the roads less traveled ... " + wanderer.getProfession() + ".");
            System.out.println("     *+1 Durability, +2 Smarts, +3 Sense*");
            dwarf.setDurability(dwarf.getDurability() + 1);
            human.setDurability(human.getDurability() + 1);
            dwarf.setSmarts(dwarf.getSmarts() + 2);
            human.setSmarts(human.getSmarts() + 2);
            dwarf.setSense(dwarf.getSense() + 3);
            human.setSense(human.getSense() + 3);
        } else if (inputProfession.equalsIgnoreCase("Scholar")) {
            System.out.println("An ever curious ... " + scholar.getProfession() + ".");
            System.out.println("     *+1 Bravado, +2 Sense, +3 Smarts*");
            dwarf.setBravado(dwarf.getBravado()+1);
            human.setBravado(human.getBravado()+1);
            dwarf.setSense(dwarf.getSense()+2);
            human.setSense(human.getSense()+2);
            dwarf.setSmarts(dwarf.getSmarts()+3);
            human.setSmarts(human.getSmarts()+3);
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Press \"ENTER\" to continue...");
        Scanner pressEnter = new Scanner(System.in);
        pressEnter.nextLine();
        System.out.println("You are a *" + inputRace + " " + inputProfession + "* and your final statistics are:");
        if (inputRace.equalsIgnoreCase("Dwarf") && inputProfession.equalsIgnoreCase("Gambler")) {
            System.out.println("Might " + (dwarf.getMight()));
            System.out.println("Reflex " + (dwarf.getReflex()));
            System.out.println("Durability " + (dwarf.getDurability()));
            System.out.println("Smarts " + (dwarf.getSmarts()));
            System.out.println("Bravado " + (dwarf.getBravado()));
            System.out.println("Fortune " + (dwarf.getFortune()));
            System.out.println("Sense " + (dwarf.getSense()));
        } else if (inputRace.equalsIgnoreCase("Dwarf") && inputProfession.equalsIgnoreCase("Bard")) {
            System.out.println("Might " + (dwarf.getMight()));
            System.out.println("Reflex " + (dwarf.getReflex()));
            System.out.println("Durability " + (dwarf.getDurability()));
            System.out.println("Smarts " + (dwarf.getSmarts()));
            System.out.println("Bravado " + (dwarf.getBravado()));
            System.out.println("Fortune " + (dwarf.getFortune()));
            System.out.println("Sense " + (dwarf.getSense()));
        } else if (inputRace.equalsIgnoreCase("Dwarf") && inputProfession.equalsIgnoreCase("Gladiator")) {
            System.out.println("Might " + (dwarf.getMight()));
            System.out.println("Reflex " + (dwarf.getReflex()));
            System.out.println("Durability " + (dwarf.getDurability()));
            System.out.println("Smarts " + (dwarf.getSmarts()));
            System.out.println("Bravado " + (dwarf.getBravado()));
            System.out.println("Fortune " + (dwarf.getFortune()));
            System.out.println("Sense " + (dwarf.getSense()));
        } else if (inputRace.equalsIgnoreCase("Dwarf") && inputProfession.equalsIgnoreCase("Pickpocket")) {
            System.out.println("Might " + (dwarf.getMight()));
            System.out.println("Reflex " + (dwarf.getReflex()));
            System.out.println("Durability " + (dwarf.getDurability()));
            System.out.println("Smarts " + (dwarf.getSmarts()));
            System.out.println("Bravado " + (dwarf.getBravado()));
            System.out.println("Fortune " + (dwarf.getFortune()));
            System.out.println("Sense " + (dwarf.getSense()));
        } else if (inputRace.equalsIgnoreCase("Dwarf") && inputProfession.equalsIgnoreCase("Wanderer")) {
            System.out.println("Might " + (dwarf.getMight()));
            System.out.println("Reflex " + (dwarf.getReflex()));
            System.out.println("Durability " + (dwarf.getDurability()));
            System.out.println("Smarts " + (dwarf.getSmarts()));
            System.out.println("Bravado " + (dwarf.getBravado()));
            System.out.println("Fortune " + (dwarf.getFortune()));
            System.out.println("Sense " + (dwarf.getSense()));
        } else if (inputRace.equalsIgnoreCase("Dwarf") && inputProfession.equalsIgnoreCase("Scholar")) {
            System.out.println("Might " + (dwarf.getMight()));
            System.out.println("Reflex " + (dwarf.getReflex()));
            System.out.println("Durability " + (dwarf.getDurability()));
            System.out.println("Smarts " + (dwarf.getSmarts()));
            System.out.println("Bravado " + (dwarf.getBravado()));
            System.out.println("Fortune " + (dwarf.getFortune()));
            System.out.println("Sense " + (dwarf.getSense()));
        } else if (inputRace.equalsIgnoreCase("Human") && inputProfession.equalsIgnoreCase("Gambler")) {
            System.out.println("Might " + (human.getMight()));
            System.out.println("Reflex " + (human.getReflex()));
            System.out.println("Durability " + (human.getDurability()));
            System.out.println("Smarts " + (human.getSmarts()));
            System.out.println("Bravado " + (human.getBravado()));
            System.out.println("Fortune " + (human.getFortune()));
            System.out.println("Sense " + (human.getSense()));
        } else if (inputRace.equalsIgnoreCase("Human") && inputProfession.equalsIgnoreCase("Bard")) {
            System.out.println("Might " + (human.getMight()));
            System.out.println("Reflex " + (human.getReflex()));
            System.out.println("Durability " + (human.getDurability()));
            System.out.println("Smarts " + (human.getSmarts()));
            System.out.println("Bravado " + (human.getBravado()));
            System.out.println("Fortune " + (human.getFortune()));
            System.out.println("Sense " + (human.getSense()));
        } else if (inputRace.equalsIgnoreCase("Human") && inputProfession.equalsIgnoreCase("Gladiator")) {
            System.out.println("Might " + (human.getMight()));
            System.out.println("Reflex " + (human.getReflex()));
            System.out.println("Durability " + (human.getDurability()));
            System.out.println("Smarts " + (human.getSmarts()));
            System.out.println("Bravado " + (human.getBravado()));
            System.out.println("Fortune " + (human.getFortune()));
            System.out.println("Sense " + (human.getSense()));
        } else if (inputRace.equalsIgnoreCase("Human") && inputProfession.equalsIgnoreCase("Pickpocket")) {
            System.out.println("Might " + (human.getMight()));
            System.out.println("Reflex " + (human.getReflex()));
            System.out.println("Durability " + (human.getDurability()));
            System.out.println("Smarts " + (human.getSmarts()));
            System.out.println("Bravado " + (human.getBravado()));
            System.out.println("Fortune " + (human.getFortune()));
            System.out.println("Sense " + (human.getSense()));
        } else if (inputRace.equalsIgnoreCase("Human") && inputProfession.equalsIgnoreCase("Wanderer")) {
            System.out.println("Might " + (human.getMight()));
            System.out.println("Reflex " + (human.getReflex()));
            System.out.println("Durability " + (human.getDurability()));
            System.out.println("Smarts " + (human.getSmarts()));
            System.out.println("Bravado " + (human.getBravado()));
            System.out.println("Fortune " + (human.getFortune()));
            System.out.println("Sense " + (human.getSense()));
        } else if (inputRace.equalsIgnoreCase("Human") && inputProfession.equalsIgnoreCase("Scholar")) {
            System.out.println("Might " + (human.getMight()));
            System.out.println("Reflex " + (human.getReflex()));
            System.out.println("Durability " + (human.getDurability()));
            System.out.println("Smarts " + (human.getSmarts()));
            System.out.println("Bravado " + (human.getBravado()));
            System.out.println("Fortune " + (human.getFortune()));
            System.out.println("Sense " + (human.getSense()));
        }
    }
}
```

Profession.java

```
public class Profession{
    private String profession;
    private String gambler;
    private String bard;
    private String gladiator;
    private String pickpocket;
    private String wanderer;
    private String scholar;

    public Profession(){
    }
    public String getProfession(){
        return profession;
    }
    public void setProfession(String profession){
        this.profession = profession;
    }
    public String getGambler(){
        return gambler;
    }
    public void setGambler(String gambler){
        this.gambler = gambler;
    }
    public String getBard(){
        return bard;
    }
    public void setBard(String bard){
        this.bard = bard;
    }
    public String getGladiator(){
        return gladiator;
    }
    public void setGladiator(String gladiator){
        this.gladiator = gladiator;
    }
    public String getPickpocket(){
        return pickpocket;
    }
    public void setPickpocket(String pickpocket){
        this.pickpocket = pickpocket;
    }
    public String getWanderer(){
        return wanderer;
    }
    public void setWanderer(String wanderer){
        this.wanderer = wanderer;
    }
    public String getScholar(){
        return scholar;
    }
    public void setScholar(String scholar){
        this.scholar = scholar;
    }
}
```